# Have a custom keystroke insert a Unicode char in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a way to get the Atom editor to insert a custom Unicode character when you press a shortcut key?  I'm trying to make Cmd-\ insert a lambda (λ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom command and then map that command to the desired key. To add the custom command you can add this to your `init.coffee`:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'custom:insert-lambda': (event) ->
    editor = @getModel()
    editor.insertText('λ')
```

Then you can add the key mapping in your `keymap.cson`:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'cmd-\\': 'custom:insert-lambda'
```

After restarting or reloading the window to load the new `init.coffee`, things should work for you.

Comment: I can get to the keycap.cson file via "Show Keybindings", but how do i get to init.coffee?

Comment: Nevermind.  I found the "Open config folder" button in settings.

Comment: Also should note that it require restarting the editor.

Comment: What is the JavaScript equivalent of this?